# Is there a way to separate a string into separate words in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to separate a long string into different words that I will print off with a .1 second delay on the same line.

Comment: look into [str.split](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through the "How to ask a good question" [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in SO Help Center. Please describe what you have tried so far, what is not working, and what is the desired output.

Comment: String `split` and `time` module help you with this. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split according to the space between them:

```
from time import sleep
string = "hello world"
words = string.split(' ') # splits the string into parts divided by ' '
for w in words:
    print(w, end=' ')
    sleep(0.1) #delays for 0.1 seconds
```

Comment: In order to keep it all on the same line you will need to apply a `,` after the print statement. i.e. `print(w),`